# How to rotate uiview on its origin using transformation

Tags: uiview, transform

I am trying use table view on horizontally. I rotated table view using .transform property it only rotates it on the center. Changing the center property undesirable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set arbitrary transformation matrix?
If yes, use one that translate it so center is on origin, then rotate and then translate it back.